# Cannot call a function within a didSet. Error message: "expression resolves to unused function"

Tags: swift, function, didset

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController
{

// The timer is used to check when the download is complete and will only allow segues when it is
var timer = Timer()
var segueName: String = ""
static var didSelectTabBar = false
static var tabBarSegueName = ""

static var startAnimation: Bool = false
{

    didSet
    {
        if startAnimation == true
        {
            updateCounting(<#T##HomeViewController#>)
            loadAnimation(<#T##HomeViewController#>)

        }
    }
}
```

The variable for the `didSet` is being changed in a separate Swift file and works, I can get to the `if` statement. But I can't get the functions to work and receive the same error message for both.

**updateCounting**

```
func updateCounting(){

    if MyVariables.allSoldiersDownloaded
    {
        HomeViewController.startAnimation = false
        loadingImageView.stopAnimating()
        loadingImageView.isHidden = true
        if HomeViewController.didSelectTabBar == false
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueName, sender: nil)
        }

        timer.invalidate()
        MyVariables().setGlobalSoldier(id: MyVariables.facebookSoldierID)
        soldierOfHourButton.setTitle("Soldier of the Hour: \(MyVariables.globalSoldier.christian_names) \(MyVariables.globalSoldier.surname)", for: UIControlState.normal)
        soldierOfHourButton.sizeToFit()

    }
    else {
        //print("Not downloaded yet")
    }
}
```

**loadAnimation**

```
func loadAnimation() {
    //creates and stores all the names for the images used in an array
    var imagesNames = ["run1-1.jpg", "run2-1.jpg", "run3-1.jpg", "run4-1.jpg", "run5-1.jpg", "run6-1.jpg", "run7-1.jpg", "run8-1.jpg", "run9-1.jpg", "run10-1.jpg", "run11-1.jpg"]

    //create new uiimage array
    var images = [UIImage]()

    //loop through all the photos in the imagesNames array and add them to the images array
    for i in 0..<imagesNames.count{
        images.append(UIImage(named: imagesNames[i])!)
    }

    //tell testview what images to use for the animation
    loadingImageView.animationImages = images

    //tell testview how long to show a single image for
    loadingImageView.animationDuration = 0.9


    //start the animation in the image view called test view
    loadingImageView.startAnimating()
    loadingImageView.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Please provide as much info as you can (for example the full stack trace), and format your questions properly (see my edits). This way you will get help much much faster.

What is the meaning of `<#T##HomeViewController#>`?

It should be just `updateCounting()` `and loadAnimation()`:

[image: Playground]

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
        updateCounting(<#T##HomeViewController#>)
        loadAnimation(<#T##HomeViewController#>)
```

with

```
        updateCounting()
        loadAnimation()
```